# Where to find an Xcode developer library on a hard disk?

Tags: xcode4.4

Where can I find a developer library in Xcode 4.4 on hard disk? Thanks!!! I want to copy it and save on the flash-drive.

Comment: All libraries, part of XCode 4.4, lie somewhere in the `/Application/Xcode.app` package. Btw, you have tagged your question `xcode4.3` and asking about Xcode 4.4 - it's confusing.

Comment: Thanks! I don't have a permission to create new tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it! ~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/